# Java classpath: Bad class file: contains wrong class

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

I have the following project structure:

```
MyProject
    +-Main.java
    +-package1
        +-ClassA.java
        +-package2
            +-ClassB.java
            +-ClassC.java
```

After compiling using `javac *.java` from the `MyProject` folder, the .class files are created in the folders where the corresponding .java files are located.

This is an overview of my Main.java file:

```java
import package1.*;
import package1.package2.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB test = new ClassB();
    }

}
```

And this is the error I get when compiling:

```
Main.java:15: error: cannot access ClassB
        ClassB test = new ClassB();
        ^
  bad class file: ./package1/package2/ClassB.class
    class file contains wrong class: package2.ClassB
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I have made sure that the package structure matches the folders.

In addition, I tried compiling the project manually by using

```sh
javac -cp package1/package2 package1/package2/*.java
javac -cp package1 package1/*.java
javac -cp . Main.java
```

Which unfortunately produces the same error.

My verdict is that this issue is caused by the location of the .class files in package2, which the compiler can't seem to handle properly but I'm not sure how to modify my project structure.

Comment: Can you show your `ClassB.java`? Does it contain `package package1.package2;` declaration?

Comment: It actually just contained `package package2;` which was the issue apparently. Thank you for saving my time :)

Comment: No problem, glad it was it : )